# How do you target THIS Parent, from a child to make another child div show using nothing but classes with pure javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I have a bunch of data thats being loaded in dynamically so I have to use classes to pull this off.

Just using pure javascript and not jquery, how do I make it so that when you click view more in a div, it makes the hidden div only show from THIS parent?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Structurally, you have a couple choices.

When `.classViewMore` is clicked, you can get the target of the event (most likely in the `this` pointer) that will be the `.classViewMore` item that was clicked on.

From that object, you can up to the parent (that gets you the `Child` item in your common parent.

From the `Child`, you can either go to a sibling to find `Hidden Child` or you can go up to the `.classDiv` parent and then find the containing `.classHiddenDiv`.

It's all about using the DOM hierarchy to find the other item that shares a common parent.  Without actual HTML, it's a little hard to give exact code, but it would be something like this:

```
function classViewMoreClickHandler(e) {
    // find next sibling of our parent
    var childElem = this.parentNode;
    var hiddenChildElem = childElem.nextSibling; 
}
```

or, going up to the .classDiv parent, it would look like this:

```
function classViewMoreClickHandler(e) {

    var parent = this.parentNode.parentNode;
    var hiddenChild = parent.querySelectorAll(".classHiddenDiv")[0];
}
```

If you're going to work in plain JS regularly, then you probably want an analog for jQuery's `.closest()` method in plain javascript which finds an ancestor that matches a specific selector which can be really, really useful for this up to some common parent kind of DOM hiearchy navigation.  For example, you could make a bit more robust solution using this:

```
function hasClass(elem, cls) {
    var str = " " + elem.className + " ";
    var testCls = " " + cls + " ";
    return(str.indexOf(testCls) != -1) ;
}

function closest(start, cls) {
    while (start && start !== document.documentElement && !hasClass(start, cls)) {
        start = start.parentNode;
    }
    return start;
}

function classViewMoreClickHandler(e) {

    var p = closest(this, ".classDiv");
    if (p) {
        var hiddenChild = p.querySelectorAll(".classHiddenDiv")[0];
        // do whatever you want to hiddenChild here
    }
}
```